# What is the life of a monk really like?

Tags: theravada, monk

I am curious to know a little bit more about the day-to-day life of Theravada buddhist monks. I am drawn to the idea of ordaining, but I fear this is only because I have romanticized the buddhist monk's life in my mind as easy and care-free; like an escape from my own life. What is monastic life like, and how do the challenges that come with this lifestyle compare with those of lay-life?
I am looking for a reality check if anyone can provide it.
Thx!

Comment: http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhistworld/wat_m5.htm

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you with romanticising monk life. Of course the day to day living of a monk varies a lot depending on whether they live in a monastery, a cave, or the forest. Despite having many hours in the day for their own practice I often see monks telling of how they have little free time.

This book called The Broken Buddha which was written by an ex-monk exposes the reality about monasticism in thailand/sri lanka/burma http://www.buddhistische-gesellschaft-berlin.de/downloads/brokenbuddhanew.pdf

Reading that drove away a lot of my dreaming of monk life because I realised the type of people I would be living with if ordaining in Asia. I still strive for a monastic lifestyle but not because of romanticised ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I don't think the author is an "ex-monk": apparently he calls himself a "Buddhist" monk now, not a "Theravada" monk (see [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shravasti_Dhammika) and [this reference](http://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=2698)).

Answer (score 2):

> What is monastic life like?

From [Nalaka Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.11.olen.html): Gurgling Loudly (excerpt) translated from the Pali by
Andrew Olendzki -

> ...
>   Listen to the sound of water
>     In the clefts and in the gullies:
>   The tiny streams gurgle loudly
>     — Mighty waters flow in silence.
>    ...
>
> ---
>
> how do the challenges?

From [Nalaka Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.11.than.html): To Nalaka translated from the Pali by Thanissaro Bhikkhu

> [Nalaka:]
>   Now that I know
>    Asita's words to be true,
>    I ask you, Gotama,
>   you who have gone
>    to the beyond of all things.
>    I'm intent on the homeless life;
>    I long for the almsround.
>    Tell me sage, when I ask you,
>   the utmost state of sagacity.
>
> [The Buddha:]
>    I'll explain to you
>    a sagacity hard to do,
>    hard to endure.
>   Come now, I'll tell you.
>    Be steadfast. Be firm.
>    Practice even-mindedness,
>    for in a village there's praise & abuse.
>    Ward off any flaw in the heart. Go about calmed & not haughty.
>    High & low things  will come up like fire-flames in a forest.
>    Women seduce a sage. May they not seduce you.[1](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.11.olen.html)
>    Abstaining from sexual intercourse, abandoning various sensual pleasures,
>    be unopposed, unattached, to beings moving & still.
>    'As I am, so are these. As are these, so am I.'
>    Drawing the parallel to yourself, neither kill nor get others to kill.
>    Abandoning the wants & greed where people run-of-the-mill are stuck,
>    practice with vision, cross over this hell.
>    Stomach not full, moderate in food,
>   having few wants, not being greedy, always not hankering after desire:
>   one without hankering, is one who's unbound.
>    Having gone on his almsround, the sage should then go to the forest,
>    standing or taking a seat at the foot of a tree.
>    The enlightened one, intent on jhana,
>   should find delight in the forest,
>    should practice jhana at the foot of a tree,
>    attaining his own satisfaction.
>   Then, at the end of the night, he should go to the village,
>    not delighting in an invitation or gift from the village.
>    Having gone to the village,
>    the sage should not carelessly go among families.
>    Cutting off chatter, he shouldn't utter a scheming word.
>    'I got something, that's fine. I got nothing, that's good.'
>    Being such with regard to both, he returns to the very same tree.
>    Wandering with his bowl in hand — not dumb, but seemingly dumb —
>   he shouldn't despise a piddling gift nor disparage the giver.
>    High & low are the practices proclaimed by the contemplative.
>    They don't go twice to the further shore.
>    This [Unbinding] isn't sensed only once.[2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.11.than.html)
>    In one who has no attachment — the monk who has cut the stream,
>    abandoning what is & isn't a duty — no fever is found.
>
> I'll explain to you sagacity:
>    be like a razor's edge.
>    Pressing tongue against palate,
>    restrain your stomach.
>   Neither be lazy in mind,
>    nor have many thoughts.
>    Be committed to taintlessness,
>    independent, having the holy life as your aim.
>     Train in solitude & the contemplative's task,
>    Solitude is called sagacity.
>     Alone, you truly delight & shine in the ten directions.
>    On hearing the fame of the enlightened
>    — those who practice jhana,
>      relinquishing sensual pleasures
>    — my disciple should
>   foster all the more conviction & conscience.
>
> Know from the rivers in clefts & in crevices:
>    those in small channels flow noisily,
>    the great flow silent.
>    Whatever's not full makes noise.
>   Whatever is full is quiet.
>    The fool is like a half-empty pot;
>    one who is wise,   a full lake.
>   A contemplative who speaks a great deal endowed with meaning:
>   knowing, he teaches the Dhamma, knowing, he speaks a great deal.
>    But he who, knowing, is restrained, knowing, doesn't speak a great deal:
>   he is a sage worthy of sagehood; he is a sage, his sagehood attained.

Answer (score 0):

Pay everyday's attention to:

1. listening meditation lesson from tipitaka-memorizer.
2. observing the 91,805,036,000 vinaya-rules.

   1. keeping to violate the prohibited rules, such as denying money, denying sex activity, etc.
   2. keeping to do the procedure rules, such as memorizing [bhikkhunissayamuccaka-course](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search?q=course), go to bowl, keeping the monk robe,  etc.
3. keeping the balancing between the virtual, the concentration meditation and the insight meditation to enlighten nibbāna.
4. develop the knowledge from [bhikkhunissayamuccaka-course](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search?q=course) to tipitaka-memorizer.